# Add Items metroTabControl

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, metro-ui-css

Can anyone tell me how to add items/controls to a metroTabControl (windows forms)? Whenever I try to do so with visual studio 2013 designer, it throws this error:

> Cannot add 'MetroLabel' to TabControl. Only TabPages can be directly
>   added to TabControls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET TabControl has a pretty fancy designer, they did not provide a very good substitute for it.  Understandably, creating designers is a lot of work and designer code is quite obscure.

Select the MetroTabControl you added, note the little black triangle that's displayed on the upper-right.  Click it and select `Add Tab`.  You can now drop the label on the added tab page.

Comment: A little Clarification: With the current version, if you use properties window in VS designer to add tabpages to the MetroTabControl, then you will run into this error. However, if you follow the instructions described above, then it'll be fine. Later you can go into the properties window to rename tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the TabPage you wish to add MetroLabel or any item to and then double click on MetroLabel or the item, it will add. Do not click and drag for that affect the TabControl and not the TabPage.

Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

As explicitly stated by the error you're experiencing, a TabControl only accepts TabPages.

Add a TabPage to the TabControl, then add a MetroLabel to that TabPage.

Comment: Thank you, but i have already done that. It always wants to drop the item to the full tab control, not to the tab page.

Answer (score 0):

Little Late but you can always place the controls somewhere on the underlying form and cut/paste them on the tab you want after you have moved the focus to it...